# How to remove Eclipse shortcut from Linux quicklaunch

Tags: eclipse, fedora, uninstallation

I tried to remove Eclipse, I deleted all the files, however there is still this icon when I open menu in Fedora 35. How can I remove it?

Thanks in advance. Sorry for noob question, I just started with Linux.

[Screenshot of the Eclipse shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee8WI.png)

Comment: There must be a place where all the launches are saved. In Ubuntu for example it's `/usr/share/applications` and filename is `eclipse.desktop`. Try to find such a file ande delete it

Comment: I checked the mentioned folder, and there is nothing with name `eclipse.desktop`